# How to test Xamarin Forms for Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have programmed a small app for Android with Xamarin Forms. I only tested the app with my Honor 7X and it works fine. Is there any other way that I can test the app for free at least on other virtual devices. I am new to Xamarin so I need some tips.

Comment: Setup Android emulator for each API level that you wish to test on locally and you should also test on physical devices (i.e. using MS App Center Test : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Visual studio, you do not need to install third-part android emulator for your test in the android part.

You can using Android SDKs and Tools to install API in your VS like following screenshot.

[image]

Then you need to [Hardware acceleration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows) for emulator performance (Hyper-V & HAXM), choose suitable Hardware acceleration.

In the end, install emulators that you needed in [device manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=windows).
[image]

[MS app center](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/app-center/pricing/) is not free, but it provide Free 30 day trial. After 30 days trial, Pay as your app grows

Comment: @Yves If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to mark it as anwer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Genymotion to testing all the API levels with different types of emulators. It's free for personal use. Refer this link,

[Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)